# Как перехватить нажатие клавиши в textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть тег `textarea`, в котором пользователь должен менять заголовок страницы. При нажатии на ENTER будут происходить определённые действия, а строка не должна переноситься.  Как это можно сделать с jQuery?

Comment: Точно так же как и не в textarea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
$('textarea').on('keydown', function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 6):

Без jquery:

```js
document.querySelector("textarea").onkeydown=function(e){
 if(e.keyCode == 13){
  alert("это, как действие");
  return false;
 }
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```